# Unity - UWP: how to deploy a HoloLens 2 app that also use Azure Kinect DK

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, azurekinect

I'm making an application for HoloLens 2 that also use Azure Kinect DK to implement some body tracking features (with walking gesture). I have been testing it smoothly in the Unity Editor using Holographic Remoting, but when I build and deploy the app onto the HoloLens 2, I got this error showing on the HoloLens:

```
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'k4a'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'k4a' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) - The specified module could not be found. (WinError: 0000007e)
```

What I've tried and failed so far:

- Put Azure Kinect's dlls into the `build\bin\ARM64\Release` folder of the visual studio UWP project that was built by Unity.
- Put Azure Kinect's dlls into the `Assets\Plugins` folder of the Unity project.

For context, I use this package to help integrate Azure Kinect DK into Unity: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/azure-kinect-examples-for-unity-149700. They put the sensor's dlls in this folder `Assets\AzureKinectExamples\SDK\Kinect4AzureSDK\Plugins`. For the body tracking SDK dlls, they copy the dlls from the `Azure Kinect Body Tracking SDK` install location to the project's root directory. This configuration works for Unity Editor and for "Windows, Mac, Linux" platform, but not for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Kinect DK does not support UWP. For more information about the operating systems and architectures currently supported by Azure Kinect DK, please refer to [Azure Kinect Sensor SDK system requirements | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/system-requirements#supported-operating-systems-and-architectures).

Answer (score 0):

So I realized Azure Kinect DK doesn't support UWP like Zuocheng Wang said. While looking for a solution I found this devpost: https://devpost.com/software/arehab, the trick is to build two separate apps, one run on your laptop/PC (Platform Windows, Mac, Linux) which is connected to Azure Kinect DK, I will call it A, the other run on the HoloLens 2 (Platform UWP), I will call it B. A will keep sending B body tracking data so that B can use it to display body-related information. The package I mentioned https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/azure-kinect-examples-for-unity-149700 even has an example that demonstrate using Azure Kinect DK over LAN.